# Smoothing time series with Adjusted R2-weighted averages

Tags: outliers, goodness-of-fit, weights, weighted-mean, weighted-data

I have two parameters (a,b) resulting from an exponential estimation of a curve. I have estimated this curve every hour for one month. In other words, I have a total of 720 parameters a and b, and I also have their adjusted R2 and their RMSE.

I want to make a monthly weighted average of each parameter where I will give more weight to the parameters with a higher R2. Is there a term in econometrics that talks about this? I am trying to look for the term, but I don't know if it exists.

Also, do you recommend using R2 or RMSE and why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have 720 curves, one for each hour, and for each of those curves you have two parameters a and b obtained from 720 different exponential fittings?

Comment: Thats right @frank :)

Comment: Why don't you put the data for all the 720 curves into one large dataset and fit a curve to that large dataset?

Comment: Because the fitting results are lost in many dots, I know that the hourly curve has an exponential shape, but if I place all the data, this shape is lost @frank